# OnCollisionEnter2D not activating despite collision clearly happening

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am working on a platformer where one of the main mechanics is that when you hit enemies from the bottom (or hit them with the top of you as actually implemented in the code) they lose health. It is clear that when running, the player character and the enemy character are indeed colliding, as they affect each other. However, OnCollisionEnter2D, which I use to get the effects, is inclined to disagree, as none of the effects happens when I use them. Here's the current code for it:

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision collision)
{
    if (collision.collider.gameObject.layer == 10)
    {
        print("yeet");  //debug text

        if (hitEnemy == true)
            collision.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<EnemyMove01>().health -= 1;
        else
            health -= 1;
    }
}
```

I tried:

- Adding and removing ".collider" from the "collision." lines.
- Adding and removing ".gameObject" from the same lines.
- Using both layers and tags for checking.
- Used both layer name and layer number for checking.
- Removing everything within outer it statement execpt for "health -= 1" and used debug text to see if the problem had anything to do with the way hitEnemy worked (apparently it does not).
- Using both OnCollisionEnter and OnCollisionEnter2D.
- Checked the collider matrix.
- Changed the enemy type to "static".
- Checked if "Is Trigger" is activated (currently it isn't).

I would appreciate any help. I am also willing to post any other things (other parts of code, BoxCollider2D/RigidBody2D stuff) if you think it would help.

Update: I have editted my code and fixed the above problem, but now the enemy character immediately disappears when I run it, even though my character isn't hitting them. Here's the current code:

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.collider.gameObject.tag == "Enemies")
    {
        print("yeet");  //debug text

        if (hitEnemy == true)
            collision.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<EnemyMove01>().health -= 1;
        else
            health -= 1;
    }
}
```

And since it might be due to hitEnemy being always true, here's it's activation code:

```
hitEnemy = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(attackpos.position, attackRange, whatisEnemies);
```

attackRange is 0.5, while attackpos is attached to a game object which is on top of the player character (I can get a screenshot if you think it would help). whatisEnemies is a layer mask set to the "Enemies" layer.

Update 2: Turns out the second problem what because I forgot to input the enemy's health. Oops.

Comment: May be a simple question but you never mention if there is a rigid body attached. So is there one attached?

Comment: I have indeed added a rigid body script to both the player character and enemy. I have also add a rigid body variable to the Player Character's movement script. Do I need to also add one to the enemy?

Comment: Try replacing "Collision collision" in the parameters to "Collision2D collision". Also, you only need rigidbody on one of the colliders.

Comment: I did that, but now the enemy character disappears (from the look of things it's basically dying) without me touching it at all. I am using an Overlap Circle to hit the enemy, and as far as I can tell the radius isn't large enough nor the center close enough to the enemy to hit it. I can show you the code for how it works if you think it would help.

Comment: Hi Constance, colliders/collisions can be a little bit confusing in terms of 'when are the callbacks being triggered'. Personally, I think that the Collision Action Matrix at the end of this link is always helpful  https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html
Good luck!

Comment: Which script is this `OnCollisionEnter2D` in? and could you edit the post to contain whatever changes to the code you have done so far?

Comment: Method signature - it should be Collision2D? If something else happens then you have more collisions happening.

Comment: Ryolu, I edited the original post to include new information and updates.

Comment: Are they maybe on different layers which are set to not interact in the physics settings?

Comment: All the boxes in the Layer Collision Matrix are checked, which I think means they can all interact with one another.

Comment: How about putting the collision detection into enemies instead and **only** have the enemies do what they need to do when they detect a collision with the player?

Comment: Seems like a good idea, I'll work on implementing it when I can.